# Cannot use regexp_substr in the old version MySQL Query Browser

Tags: mysql, sql, regex

I am using MYSQL Query Browser version 1.2.11, and write the below SQL query cannot work in MYSQL Query Browser version 1.2.11.

```html
select id,name
  from(select t.*,cast(regexp_substr(name,'[0-9]+') as unsigned) col1
                 ,cast(regexp_substr(name,'[0-9]+',1,2) as unsigned) col2
                 ,cast(regexp_substr(name,'[0-9]+',1,3) as unsigned) col3
                 ,cast(regexp_substr(name,'[0-9]+',1,4) as unsigned) col4
  from filing_code_management t) c
order by col1,col2,col3,col4
```

I have tried this SQL query to use in the online dbfiddle, just `SQL 8.0` can work in https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=e43d94d0418854375a07c2bbf1e44339

May I know got any method can replace this SQL query code to suitable in my old `MYSQL DB version 5.5`? My side need to use old version to run the SQL. Hope someone can guide me, thanks.

The error appears **FUNCTION db_12668458.regexp_substr does not exist** in This old version of DB.

Comment: The output from your demo contains neither `col1`, `col2`, `col3`, or `col4`.  In any case, you _can't_ easily replicate the functionality of MySQL 8+ `REGEXP_SUBSTR` in earlier versions.  You would probably either have to use a UDF which does the same, or just handle this requirement outside of MySQL.

Comment: Please provide sample data, desired results, and explain the logic you want to implement.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Thanks for you answer. Can you guide me or show me how to use UDF which does the same?

Comment: @GordonLinoff My sample data in here https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.5&fiddle=e43d94d0418854375a07c2bbf1e44339

Comment: The result is same in dbfiddle, but it just can used in SQL 8.0, earlier versions cannot use.